# Searchable not showing in a tabview with page style

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I made a basic project to test the simple functionality of having the search bar inside each of the views contained in a page style Tabview.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink {
            SearchView()
        } label: {
            Text("Open Search")
        }
        .searchable(text: .constant("query..."))
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
}}
```

[image]

```
struct SearchView: View {
var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("First")
                //.searchable(text: .constant("query..."))
            Text("Second")
                //.searchable(text: .constant("query..."))
            Text("Third")
                //.searchable(text: .constant("query..."))
            Text("Fourth")
                //.searchable(text: .constant("query..."))
        }
        .searchable(text: .constant("query..."))
        .navigationTitle("Search view")
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
}}
```

[image]

I just want to have the search bar visible on all the views contained in the tabview. I tried pretty much everything, putting searchable on all textviews, embedding textviews in navigationview and adding searchable, nothing works.
Is there something I'm missing or its just that SwiftUI cannot handle this simple use case?

Comment: TabView should always be at the top per HIG, each tab can have its own NavigationView/Stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the searchable modifier only works on the top of the view hierarchy. So you have to create your own search bar and customize it.